# First Attempt of SQlConnection.open method on UWP app takes longer than desktop application

Tags: vb.net, uwp, sqlconnection

I have created a UWP app on windows 10, version 1803 SDK version 17134. 
SQL Server version is 2008 R2 (SP2).
For my application its necessary to connect to SQL server on network server. Here I encountered that when I launch my app for the first time and then I call connect to sql using the code below :

```
Dim st as Stopwatch
st.start() 
Dim cn as new SQLConnection("server=192.168.0.254;initial catalog=mydb;user id=user123;password=pwd123")
cn.open()
cn.close()
st.stop()
```

First execution of the above code after application launch takes 13 to 15 seconds, then after it takes just 5 to 100 milliseconds. then again if i restart it follows same cycle. 
The same code on windows desktop app on the same system is able to open connection in < 200 ms in the first attempt and then after in less that  20 ms. 
So how can I solve this issue and decrease the connection time to improve application performance.

Comment: I have tested following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases), and the uwp connect to server fast, have your excluded the network issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, thanks for response, I have followed the same document which you provided, only diff is I have to provide user id password in connection string. Also, I have checked that TCP and browser services are enable on the server. I am not getting "Have your excluded the network issue?", so please explain. In your test how much time it is taking ?

Comment: Less than one second. very fast.

Comment: Less then 1 second for the first time connection!!!!  great, then what could be the problem with me? Any suggestions? As mentioned in the post I get quick response in desktop app but not in uwp

Comment: emm, you could check if there is http proxy in your device.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT , I am sorry for late reply. there is no proxy in my device.

Comment: Have you ever had a situation where you can't connect to sql server?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew , No Every time I am able to connect to sql server without any problem.

Comment: Since you could connect to sql server success, you could exclude code issue. you could check network Firewall Rules.